# Facing problem whenever I compile my work

Tags: texstudio, input-encodings

Whenever I compile my work on LaTeX I always have this error

```
Problem (package inputenc error: keyboard character used undefined (inputenc) in inputencoding'latin9')
```

What does it mean and how to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Which editor do you use?

Answer (score 1):

This error message means that your tex file contains a symbol ("character"), which is not allowed.

You might be able to solve this error by

- changing the encoding in your editor to match the encoding you specified for the package `inputenc`. You really should do this, otherwise the same issue will appear again every time you type an illegal character.
- having a look at the logfile a few lines above the error message, it should contain some line numbers or text passages that you can find in your document. Then go a bit further and have a look at the characters. Any non-ASCII characters are potential candidates, i.e. most symbols outside the `A-Z` and `a-z` range.